# Can we specify delimiters explicitly for hive views?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I'm trying a create a temporary table with delimiter '\u0001' from an existing table with delimiter ',' in hive. I'm creating the temporary table first and using a view created from the existing table (since I need to do some replace function from existing table) I populate the temporary table. My question is it possible to create a view where I can explicitly specify the delimiter?

Thanks!

Comment: Should be possible due to documentation: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-CreateView and as table property you should be able to set delimited https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-AlterTable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't specify the delimiter explicitly for Hive Views.

It will inherit the properties from the table given in SELECT statement.

```
CREATE VIEW [IF NOT EXISTS] [db_name.]view_name [(column_name [COMMENT column_comment], ...) ]
  [COMMENT view_comment]
  [TBLPROPERTIES (property_name = property_value, ...)]
  AS SELECT ...;
```